# What is wrong with my if else statements for my rock paper scissor game?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am attempting to make a Rock Paper Scissors game in JavaScript, however, every time I run it the console logs the last option "You win! Scissors beats Paper" even if my selection was something other than scissors. I believe I made an error with my if else statements but maybe the problem comes from some other part.

```
function getComputerChoice() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    switch(randomNumber) {
        case 0:
            return "rock";
        case 1: 
            return "paper";
        case 2:
            return "scissors";
    };
    }


function getPlayerChoice() {
    prompt("rock paper or scissors?").toLowerCase();
}




 function playRound (playerSelection,computerSelection) {
    computerSelection = getComputerChoice()
    playerSelection = getPlayerChoice()

    

        

    if (computerSelection === playerSelection) {
        console.log  ("Tie");
    }
   
    else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "scissors") {
        console.log ("You lose! Rock beats Scissors");
    }
    else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "rock") {
        console.log ("You lose! Paper beats Rock");
    }
    else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "paper") {
        console.log ("You lose! Scissors beats Paper");
    }

    else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
        console.log ("You win! Rock beats Scissors");
    }
    else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") {
        console.log ("You win! Paper beats Rock");
    }
    else  (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") ;{
        console.log ("You win! Scissors beats Paper");
    }


}
```

Comment: You can't use `else` with condition inside use else if instead, it will work without else. Also, remove the semicolon ending in the switch case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that makes the code not run as it should. The first is that your function `getPlayerChoice()` does not return any values. As a result, `playerSelection === undefined` instead of your intended values. Since your `if` statements don't account for that, they all end up `false`. This leads to your `else` statement being executed.

It should be:

```
function getPlayerChoice() {
    return prompt("rock paper or scissors?").toLowerCase();
}
```

The second is that `else` should not have a condition inside it.

Solution:

```
else {
        console.log ("You win! Scissors beats Paper");
}
```

Note that you don't need the semicolon after your `switch` statement in your first function, but it doesn't seem to cause the code to malfunction.